# Simple recursion in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Could someone give a simple XSLT code, which will be using multiple templates in order to do a simple recursion. For example code will be adding to variable (or something similiar) a constant value. If someone have found sample of similiar code please paste a link.

Comment: Why would "simple recursion" involve multiple templates? Which XSLT version do you want to use? Are you aware that there are libraries in XSLT 1 (like EXSLT) (example http://exslt.org/str/functions/replace/str.replace.template.xsl) or XSLT 2 (functx, fxsl) where you could look for examples, not to speak of the various examples of recursive functions in the XSLT and XPath 2 or 3 specs (example https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-for-each).

Comment: Show what you want to achieve, show what you attempted, we'll explain why it's wrong. Asking for tutorials is not what SO is for. There are plenty of those around, though the best ones are in book form and cost money.